# Активация кода в строковой переменной

Tags: python

Давно хотел управлять компьютером через телефон, но проблема в том, что я хочу найти возможность активировать код, который будет помещён в строковую переменную (для передачи).
Я смог найти только этот способ...

```py
Code = """def Func():
    print("Hello!")
    return True
"""
def Use(CODE):
    with open("Func.py", "w") as File:
        File.write(CODE)
    import Func
    return Func.Func()
print(Use(Code))
```

Есть способ лучше?

Comment: Если вы конкретизируете действия, которые необходимо выполнить, возможно, получите более точный ответ.

Comment: Ну так то есть `eval()`, `exec()`, но это, мягко говоря, очень небезопасно.

Comment: @CrazyElf вот все говорят о небезопасности, а в чем конкретно оно выражается если программа работает локально для одного юзера?

Comment: @Amgarak в данном случае (если по задумке ТС будет использоваться кодогенерация) "опасность" состоит в первую очередь в выполнении некорректного кода, аварийном завершении процесса.

Comment: @Amgarak Оставлять лишние дыры в безопасности - ну, такое. Как знать, как эта штука планируется у пользователя использоваться. Потом окажется, что к ней снаружи есть доступ - и будет весело. )

Comment: @CrazyElf с такими доводами можно до чего хочешь докопаться, скажем sql не безопасен, ведь попади в бд вредоносный код и будет весело;))

Comment: @user207200 разве мы не можем обработать ошибки от вызова exec/зла... Опять таки, пиши хороший код, падать не будет;))

Comment: @Amgarak Ну хотя бы про `SQL Injection` вы в курсе? ))

Comment: @CrazyElf так я на то и намекаю;)) что дело тут не в безопасности, а в архитектуре приложения и его защите от банальных инжектов.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно, вам подойдёт функция `exec()`. Она позволяет исполнять динамический код, представленный в виде строкового выражения или блока кода.

Синтаксис:

`exec(object, globals, locals)`

- `object` - строка, содержащая код для выполнения, или блок кода.
- `globals` (необязательный параметр) - словарь, содержащий глобальные символы и их значения.
- `locals` (необязательный параметр) - словарь, содержащий локальные символы и их значения.

Подробней здесь:
[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)